# Is it possible to include multiple time slot choices in a calendar event in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to add multiple choices to an email w/ calendar event via Microsoft Outlook. Is it even possible to do that, as I'm having trouble looking up how to do so, or the buttons suggesting that I can complete the feat.

Comment: I haven't done this before, but I have seen people send polls, and when accepting an invitation, people can propose a new time...

Comment: Do you mean adding a Doodle poll?

Comment: No, I believe that there's integrated support for a poll. The options are shown in the header or something and people can select one. I only saw it a couple times, but I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: I think I found what you're talking about: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/sending-polls-in-outlook-2007/ This option should be suffice.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would be but if so I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send polls in an email through Outlook. It will give the recipients a list of options to pick from.

From: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/sending-polls-in-outlook-2007/

In Outlook 2007, to create a poll, you have to add voting buttons to your message. In the ribbon, click the Options tab and then click "Use voting buttons". There are a few options preset for you but you can also specify a custom list. If you choose a custom list, you will then be able to specify them as a text field, with each option separated by a semicolon. For instance, say I have a poll for pizza options for lunch. If I want the options "Taco", "Pepperoni", and "Sausage", I would specify the voting buttons like so: `Taco;Pepperoni;Sausage`.

To view the results of the poll, you then must open the original message and click the "Tracking" button in the ribbon. It will then show the number of votes for each option, for those who voted.